# Android MapActivity onLongPress / zooming mix up

Tags: android, overlay, itemizedoverlay, mapactivity, gesturedetector

I have a class extending `MapActivity` which has an overlay attached to it extending `ItemizedOverlay`.  Inside the overlay I have a `GestureDetector` and a `OnGestureListener`.  Now for my problem:

I have an action which triggers in the `onLongPress` of the `OnGestureListener` but `Android` triggers this even when you zoom in / out using the "pinch" gesture.  This is due to the fact that one finger tends to stay in one spot while the other one moves towards / away.  What kind of calls or checks could be implemented to detect whether the action is a pinch-zoom or a longPress, so I know to either handle or disregard in `onLongPress`?