# Android, the onLongPress event and zooming are mixed up

Tags: android, events, zooming, long-press

Good evening, 
please I have the same question already asked but not answered,([Android MapActivity onLongPress / zooming mix up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7311639/2969783))

this is the question :

I have a class extending `MapActivity` which has an overlay attached to it extending `ItemizedOverlay`. Inside the overlay I have a `GestureDetector` and a `OnGestureListener`. Now for my problem:

I have an action which triggers in the `onLongPress` of the `OnGestureListener` but Android triggers this even when you zoom in / out using the "pinch" gesture. This is maibe due to the fact that one finger tends to stay in one spot while the other one moves towards / away. What kind of calls or checks could be implemented to detect whether the action is a pinch-zoom or a `longPress`, so I know to either handle or disregard in onLongPress?

thank you.

Comment: Why don't you detect if there are 2 fingers on the screen?  If there's 2 assume pinch to zoom, if there's only 1 assume long press.

Comment: I tryed  `public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getPointerCount() == 1) {
                       // my code 
                    }
                    
                }`
but is still detecting executing longPress when I use two fingers